# ffmpeg framerate inconsistent

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

ffmpeg is being run with the same arguments but different inputs in two separate places in my code. The framerate is set to 12fps with -framerate. In one case the output video matches the framerate pretty well every time. In the other case the video is coming back with 1 second of video for every 15 input frames, but again it is consistent. What could possibly be causing the discrepancy?

Arguments:
-y -framerate 12 -itsoffset -654ms -i "C:\path/%06d.JPG"  -i "C:\path/audio.mp3" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -vf scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart "C:\path\output.mp4"

There are dozens of differences in the code that calls it but I can't understand how any of that would influence the framerate. I tried switching out the mp3 with one of an arbitrary different length to see if that had an effect but it did not. That leaves only the image inputs.

edit: So it gets stranger. I reproduced both cases and modified the framerate value for each to check what happened. In almost every case I got more seconds of video than expected. I was doing these tests with 400 frames and 5 seconds of audio to ensure the lack of -shortest wasn't a factor. The only time I got a perfectly accurate framerate was when it was set to 1. In every other case (except the verbatim 12fps in the case that was always working) the video was too short by 5-15%. This makes it a bit of a mystery how either part of my code ever produced good results.

Comment: What's the itsoffset for?

Comment: The audio and video are recorded separately, that is the difference in start times between the two recordings to synchronise them. There is an issue there, in that it should not be such a large number, but I was assuming that was an issue in my recording code and not in ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out simply replacing -framerate with -r fixes this issue. I would still appreciate some clarification about this if anyone can explain though.

Comment: Hmm but -r stops the offset from working. Also, the issue seems to have been partially caused buy the bitrate of the sound file. When I changed my sound recording setup, that seemed to effect the framerate I get with -framerate 12.
So now I am even more confused.